# NSManagedObject.h file not found error

Tags: ios, core-data

My SignupInfo.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class NSManagedObject;

@interface SignupInfo : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * firstName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * lastName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * sex;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * email;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * zipcode;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * password;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * retypepassword;


@end
```

My SignupInfo.m

```
#import "SignupInfo.h"
#import "NSManagedObject.h"


@implementation SignupInfo

@dynamic firstName;
@dynamic lastName;
@dynamic sex;
@dynamic email;
@dynamic zipcode;
@dynamic password;
@dynamic retypepassword;

@end
```

I am getting build error saying `NSManagedObject.h file not found`

I am using Core data model for SignupInfo

Comment: This is probably another bug with current Xcode version.  Randomly, I encountered the same.  Just delete only the that managed object file and try again will get it created properly.

Comment: It also happens when you forget to flag a parent Core Data entity as "Abstract".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NSManagedObject` is defined in a .h file that is included by `<CoreData/CoreData.h>`. Therefore, you do not need to declare it, and you do not need the #import statement.

Comment: That's right , but then my NSManagedObject for signupInfo doesn't find the property on it. I get the error "Property firstName not found on object type NSManagedObject"

Comment: In that case, there is something wrong with your data model. Did you look at your .xcdatamodeld file?

Comment: I think that might be the case, Can I completely delete the data model and recreate it with some changes?

Comment: Why not? You may also need to delete your actual datastore. On a device, delete your App. On the simulator, find where your App is stored and delete it.

Answer (score 2):

Have same issue when I created NSManagedObject subclass in workspace.

Use follow declaration then the problem gone.

```
#import <CoreData/NSManagedObject.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the `@class NSManagedObject;`
2. Make sure you have the Core Data framework imported (depending on the target OS).

Comment: You have something else wrong with your project.  Can you recreate your issue in a test case and upload that?  I am willing to bet this will not recreate in a test...

Answer (score 1):

`#import "NSManagedObject.h` Remove this statement and `@class`  Statement No need of it

Answer (score 1):

I get this error when I create an NSMangedObject subclass but the Group is set to the workspace or project. If you choose as your Group the first FOLDER that has the same name as your project the error shouldn't occur and you shouldn't have to modify any files that are generated when creating NSMangedObject subclasses.[image]

Answer (score 1):

This appears to happen if you perform a *Create NSManagedObject Subclass* before you add **CoreData.framework** to your project's **Build Phases/Link Binary With Libraries** section. To fix the issue, simply run the action again after you have added the framework.